# propertyMissing behaviour for inner classes

Tags: groovy

I have this facility

```
def application = new Application()
application {
    onClose {
        dispose
    }
}
```

Class resolution for that looks like this

```
class Application {
    def call(Closure cl) {
        cl.delegate = this
        cl.setResolveStrategy Closure.DELEGATE_ONLY
        cl()
    }

    def onClose(Closure cl) {
        def closeActions = new CloseActions()
        cl.delegate = closeActions
        cl.setResolveStrategy Closure.DELEGATE_ONLY
        cl()
    }

    class CloseActions {
    }
}
```

When I run this code I get `MissingPropertyException`

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: dispose for class: Application
```

It could not find the property inside class `Application`! While it supposed to be not found inside `CloseActions` as I delegated content of `onClose` closure to `CloseActions` class using `delegate` property.

When I add property `dispose` to `CloseActions` class

```
class CloseActions {
    def dispose
}
```

It does not throw the exception.
When I add `propertyMissing` to `CloseActions` class

```
class CloseActions {
    def propertyMissing(String name) {
        println "Missing property: $name"
    }
}
```

it still throws

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: dispose for class: Application
```

However when I move `CloseActions` class outside `Application` - it works fine!

Why it does not invoke `propertyMissing` method for inner classes?

Comment: Looks like https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-4737

Comment: @tim_yates I see. Well whatever.